# Factorial Length‎

Tags: factorial

I want to know:For Example:how many digits 10! is without calculate it I need a formula to count for any Integer.Is there formula to calculate the digits of any Integer number?

Comment: What does $\log_{10} n$ gives?

Comment: Its not my Answer but log(n) means n = 10 ^y and when n is 10 y = 1 so the answer is 1 but is my question the answer of 10! is 7

Comment: so, let n=10!, what's the problem with that?

Comment: I want to count this without counting n!(n*(n-1)*(n-2)) but is your formula I still see 10!

Comment: then look at Alex's answer for more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working in the decimal system you need to take the logarithm with base $10$, round down and add 1.

For $10!$ the number of digits is therefore $\left \lfloor \log_{10} (10!) \right \rfloor + 1$.

Comment: I want to count this without counting n!(n*(n-1)*(n-2)) but is your formula I still see 10!

Comment: To generalize to $n!$ with larger $n$, make use of Stirlings's approximation $n!\approx n^n\mathrm e^{-n}\sqrt {2\pi n}$, so $\log_{10}n\approx n(\log_{10}n -\log_{10}\mathrm e)+\frac12\log_{10} n +\log_{10}\sqrt{2\pi}$. With $n=10$ this latter approximation gives $6.556145\ldots$ whereas the exact value of $\log_{10}10!$ is $6.559763\ldots$; the aprroximation is already quite close and both the exact and the approximate value give $7$ digits after applying floor and adding one (as per Alex' formula).

Comment: This formula is good but I think it's not accurate enough but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the exact formula:

```
numDigits(n!) = ceiling(log10(1) + log10(2) + ... + log10(n))
```

Or the approximate formula:

```
numDigits(n!) = floor((ln(2*pi*n)/2+n*(ln(n)-1))/ln(10))+1
```

Note that log10 is logarithm base 10 and ln is logarithm base e. Also note that it is an open question whether the approximate formula gives correct answers for large n.
See this discussion: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19170/how-good-is-kamenetskys-formula-for-the-number-of-digits-in-n-factorial/44927#44927